# Passing data from map to child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass a variable from a parent component to a child component using React and Typescript.

I have a component called Table (parent) with the following map. It assigns the variable 'data' the value of the last element in the array.

```
  let data  = null;

  props.posts.map((post, index, row) => {
    if (index + 1 === row.length) {
      data = index + post.owned_asset_count;
      return console.log(data);
      // Last one.
    } else {
      return null;
      // Not last one.
    }
  });
```

I am trying to use this variable in another component, Form (child), for 'Total nfts found:'.

```
 <div className="form-results">
    <p>Showing NFT collections for address: {submittedText}</p>
    <p>Total nfts found:  </p>
    <p>Total nfts prics: </p>
  </div>
```

I have tried passing the value as a prop but am getting an error:

```
Type '{ data: null; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { submittedText: any; }'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { submittedText: any; }'.
```

Here is my full code below:

App.tsx

```
import "./App.css";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import Table from "./components/Table";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";

import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import LightModeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LightMode";
import DarkModeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DarkMode";

export const ThemeContext = createContext<any>(null);

function App() {
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState<any | null>(null);
  const [submittedText, setSubmittedText] = useState<any | null>(null);

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((curr) => (curr === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      <div className="App" id={theme}>
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={4}
          direction="row"
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent="center"
          style={{ minHeight: "10vh" }}
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Header></Header>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <div className="switch">
              <IconButton sx={{ ml: -1 }} onClick={toggleTheme} color="inherit">
                {theme === "dark" ? (
                  <LightModeIcon style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
                ) : (
                  <DarkModeIcon style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
                )}
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Form
          enteredText={enteredText}
          setEnteredText={setEnteredText}
          submittedText={submittedText}
          setSubmittedText={setSubmittedText}
        />
        <Table submittedText={submittedText} />
      </div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Form.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Form({
  enteredText,
  setEnteredText,
  submittedText,
  setSubmittedText,
}) {
  const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
    setEnteredText(i.target.value);
    console.log({ submittedText });
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmittedText(enteredText);
    setEnteredText("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="form">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <label>
          <input
            className="input-element"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter an Ethereum address or ENS name"
            value={enteredText}
            onChange={textChangeHandler}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" className="input-button"></input>
      </form>
      <div className="form-results">
        <p>Showing NFT collections for address: {submittedText}</p>
        <p>Total nfts found: </p>
        <p>Total nfts prics: </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Table.tsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";

function Table({ submittedText }, props) {
  console.log(submittedText);

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?asset_owner=" +
          submittedText +
          "&offset=0&limit=300"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        //setPosts(res.data.assets)
        setPosts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [submittedText]);

  let data = null;

  props.posts.map((post, index, row) => {
    if (index + 1 === row.length) {
      data = index + post.owned_asset_count;
      return console.log(data);
      // Last one.
    } else {
      return null;
      // Not last one.
    }
  });

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="collection-results">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Collection</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Floor</th>
            <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {posts.map((post, index) => (
            <tr key={post.id}>
              <td className="counterCell"></td>
              <td>
                <img src={post.image_url} alt="img" width="50px"></img>{" "}
                {post.name}
              </td>
              <td key={post.id}> {post.owned_asset_count}</td>
              <td key={post.id}> {post.stats.average_price.toFixed(4)}</td>
              <td key={post.id}>
                {" "}
                {post.owned_asset_count * post.stats.average_price.toFixed(4)}
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div></div>
      <Table data={data}/>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: This website does a decent job in explaining typescript errors if you paste it there. In your case - https://ts-error-translator.vercel.app/?error=CoTwDgpgBA5A3lAJgQwC7IFxQHYFcA2+A3FAL4xQCWAzjgPapTLXWUDm2yARvtKnVFThoMAJLZUAJ0rZWAYwCCqKZS65UEWgDIoCari4BbSsoiJgEAB6osybCBLkAdACgoUAAqS6kSUNgo6BSIdJr0jFY0jHTYgsKw4iqylIrK0moa2rpQ+kYmGuZWNkz2jjBOQA

Answer (score 0):

First of all, react wouldn't rerender on changing variable strict, that's why you have to use useState. something like this
in Table.tsx

```
const [data, setData] = useState<number | null>(null)
...
    if (index + 1 === row.length) {
      setData(index + post.owned_asset_count)
```

**But** as for me, you got some problems here:

1. you're trying to use **Table** component inside the **Table** component. I've never tried it, but not sure how this will work. looks like you tried to put **Form** instead, but you already used **Form** in **App** component.
2. in **Table** component you have to set which props you're using(error you're getting). in **App** you put *submittedText* but in **Table** you put *data*
3. to be honest, I can't figure what you're trying to make. If I'm right, you tried something like this

App.tsx

```
function App() {
  const [submittedText, setSubmittedText] = useState<any | null>(null);  
  const [postCount, setPostCount] = useState<number>(0);
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((curr) => (curr === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      <div className="App" id={theme}>
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={4}
          direction="row"
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent="center"
          style={{ minHeight: "10vh" }}
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Header></Header>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <div className="switch">
              <IconButton sx={{ ml: -1 }} onClick={toggleTheme} color="inherit">
                {theme === "dark" ? (
                  <LightModeIcon style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
                ) : (
                  <DarkModeIcon style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
                )}
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
{/* do you need Form here? */}
        <Form
          postCount={postCount}
          submittedText={submittedText}
          setSubmittedText={setSubmittedText}
        />
        <Table submittedText={submittedText} setPostCount={setPostCount} />
      </div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Table.tsx

```
function Table({ submittedText, setPostCount }) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?asset_owner=" +
          submittedText +
          "&offset=0&limit=300"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res); 
        const posts = res.data
        setPosts(posts);

// set count of last post(owned_asset_count) + index. i'm using array.pop() to cut last value from array
        setPostCounts(posts.pop().owned_asset_count + posts.length)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [submittedText]);

  return (
    <div className="collection-results">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Collection</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Floor</th>
            <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {posts.map((post, index) => (
            <tr key={post.id}>
              <td className="counterCell"></td>
              <td>
                <img src={post.image_url} alt="img" width="50px"></img>{" "}
                {post.name}
              </td>
              <td key={post.id}> {post.owned_asset_count}</td>
              <td key={post.id}> {post.stats.average_price.toFixed(4)}</td>
              <td key={post.id}>
                {" "}
                {post.owned_asset_count * post.stats.average_price.toFixed(4)}
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>

{/* I deleted Table component, but if you need to duplicate Form here, you have to send props through Table like <Table
          enteredText={enteredText}
          setEnteredText={setEnteredText}
          submittedText={submittedText}
          setSubmittedText={setSubmittedText}
        /> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

**Form.tsx**

```
function Form({
  postCount,
  submittedText,
  setSubmittedText,
}) {
const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState<any | null>(null);
  const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
    setEnteredText(i.target.value);
    console.log({ submittedText });
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmittedText(enteredText);
    setEnteredText("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="form">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <label>
          <input
            className="input-element"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter an Ethereum address or ENS name"
            value={enteredText}
            onChange={textChangeHandler}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" className="input-button"></input>
      </form>
      <div className="form-results">
        <p>Showing NFT collections for address: {submittedText}</p>
        <p>Total nfts found: {postCount}</p>
        <p>Total nfts prics: </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Hope it'll help otherwise tell please what you tried to make?